# Select only the most descriptive rows for each combination of values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

I have a table with rows that contain various amount of information, grouped by `GroupingColumn`, as in the following example:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| GroupingColumn | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 |
|----------------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| g              | a       | b       | c       | d       | e       |
| g              | j       | k       | l       | m       | n       |
| g              | a       | b       | c       | d       | NULL    |
| g              | a       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    |
| g              | NULL    | NULL    | c       | d       | e       |
| g              | x       | y       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    |
| g              | x       | z       | w       | NULL    | NULL    |
| g              | J       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    |
| q              | a       | b       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    |
| q              | x       | z       | v       | NULL    | NULL    |
| q              | x       | z       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    |
| q              | NULL    | NULL    | e       | o       | p       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

From the table above, I would like to select only the most descriptive rows, therefore excluding the ones will less information, considering that the filtering should be done for each `GroupingColumn` value. This would result in the following:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| GroupingColumn | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 |
|----------------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| g              | a       | b       | c       | d       | e       |
| g              | j       | k       | l       | m       | n       |
| g              | x       | y       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    |
| g              | x       | z       | w       | NULL    | NULL    |
| q              | a       | b       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    |
| q              | x       | z       | v       | NULL    | NULL    |
| q              | NULL    | NULL    | e       | o       | p       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The following rows will be excluded:

- `g a b c d NULL`
- `g a NULL NULL NULL NULL`
- `g NULL NULL c d e`
- `q j NULL NULL NULL NULL`
- `q x z NULL NULL NULL`

as there are more descriptive ones holding the same values.

Notably, there can be variations of the amount of information a row can hold and is not necessary that if Column1 does not have a value, the other columns will not either.

So far, I have tried (and succeeded) only by doing this for two columns, as with the following query:

```
WITH DetailedRows(GroupingColumn, Column1)
AS
(
    SELECT GroupingColumn, Column1
    FROM TheTable
    WHERE Column2 IS NOT NULL
),
FilteredRows(GroupingColumn, Column1, Column2)
AS
(
    SELECT GroupingColumn, Column1, Column2
    FROM TheTable
    WHERE Column1 IN (SELECT Column1 FROM DetailedRows WHERE GroupingColumn = TheTable.GroupingColumn)
    AND Column2 IS NOT NULL
    UNION
    SELECT GroupingColumn, Column1, NULL
    FROM TheTable
    WHERE Column1 NOT IN (SELECT Column1 FROM DetailedRows WHERE GroupingColumn = TheTable.GroupingColumn)
)
SELECT * FROM FilteredRows
ORDER BY GroupingColumn, Column1, Column2
```

But I have a feeling this can be done more efficiently, especially when considering all the 5 columns.

Any ideas for achieving this are warmly welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. You say the "most descriptive" and grouped by GroupingColumn but in your desired output it looks like you also want to include Column1? So that you get the "most descriptive" for each combination of GroupingColumn and Column1. What are you going to do when you have a tie? Say there is a row where only Column4 is null on one and Column5 is null on the next.

Comment: Based on sample data, I'm assuming it's not possible to have a row where Col2 is NULL and Col3 has a value?

Comment: @TabAlleman, in the output the row will not be shown if Col3 is any of the other listed values (`c, l, w` for `g`, or `v` for `q`). For any other value of Col3, the row would be shown even if Col2 is NULL.

Comment: @SeanLange, Column1 will be considered as all the other numbered columns. Essentially, the GroupingColumn can be taken as all the others, only that it will never be NULL, whereas all the others can. In the example you have given, at the moment both rows will be shown as one of them is not a _superset_ of the other (thanks to Tab Alleman for the keyword)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question - I had to think about this one for a while.

If you sort your data by, e.g. `Column1 desc, Column2 desc, ...` then supersets will be adjacent to their corresponding subsets (or vice versa). For example, if we sort your sample data we get

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| GroupingColumn | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 |
|----------------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| g              | x       | z       | w       | NULL    | NULL    |
| g              | x       | y       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    |
| g              | j       | k       | l       | m       | n       |
| g              | j       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | <--
| g              | a       | b       | c       | d       | e       |
| g              | a       | b       | c       | d       | NULL    | <--
| q              | x       | z       | v       | NULL    | NULL    |
| q              | a       | b       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can see that the two rows to be excluded (as subsets of more descriptive rows) are located immediately below those superset rows.

Therefore the problem can be solved by

- sorting in this manner, and including a row number
- left joining that result to itself (handling `nulls`) on `rownum - 1`
- adding a `where` clause to exclude anything that successfully joined, as a join indicates a true subset

Having said all that - build the row number with a CTE and use it in a self join. Here's the query

```
with sorted as
(
    select *, row_number() over (partition by GroupingColumn order by Column1 desc, 
        Column2 desc, Column3 desc, Column4 desc, Column5 desc) as rnum
    from TheTable
)
select t.GroupingColumn, t.Column1, t.Column2, t.Column3, t.Column4, t.Column5 
from sorted as t 
left outer join sorted as super
    on t.GroupingColumn = super.GroupingColumn and t.rnum - 1 >= super.rnum
    and coalesce(t.Column1, super.Column1, '') = coalesce(super.Column1, '')
    and coalesce(t.Column2, super.Column2, '') = coalesce(super.Column2, '')
    and coalesce(t.Column3, super.Column3, '') = coalesce(super.Column3, '')
    and coalesce(t.Column4, super.Column4, '') = coalesce(super.Column4, '')
    and coalesce(t.Column5, super.Column5, '') = coalesce(super.Column5, '')
where super.rnum is null;
```

---

Sample data for testing

```
create table TheTable (GroupingColumn char, Column1 char, Column2 char, 
    Column3 char, Column4 char, Column5 char)
insert into TheTable select 'g', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'
union all select 'g', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n'
union all select 'g', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', null
union all select 'g', 'x', 'y', null, null, null
union all select 'g', 'x', 'z', 'w', null, null
union all select 'g', 'j', null, null, null, null
union all select 'q', 'a', 'b', null, null, null
union all select 'q', 'x', 'z', 'v', null, null;
```

Comment: thank you for the very well thought out solution. I have tested the query and it runs perfectly except for one case, which I did not mention at first – there can be more than one subset for a given row, which now is listed in the example for the `g a b c d e` superset.

Comment: The solution should have handled that but you pointed out a bug - we need to `coalesce` the *right* side of all those `=` statements in the where clause, because the superset can have null values too. I've updated and it will work for you now.

Comment: Yes, that part now works very well Kirk, I think there is only one problem left: when the first numbered columns are null, and the others are not, they will not be filtered out. This can be seen in the fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ff396/1

Comment: This changes the problem significantly. Based on this comment - which you didn't correct, but seems upvoted - I assumed that couldn't happen. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49033330/select-only-the-most-descriptive-rows-for-each-combination-of-values/49036253?noredirect=1#comment85072069_49033330 Now you introduce ambiguity - what are there are multiple possible supersets? This solution won't work in that case, as it relies on the sorting sequence. Frankly you should have included that case in the question!

Comment: I am sorry for not including that case as well at first Kirk, the upvote is not from me but I have tried to explain that the case can happen with my response (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49033330/select-only-the-most-descriptive-rows-for-each-combination-of-values/49036253?noredirect=1#comment85072218_49033330). Nevertheless, thank you for giving thought to this question, your solution will surely still help achieving the requirement.

Comment: So you asked me to change my answer twice but didn't even upvote? rofl :)

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant the comment's upvote – I have indeed upvoted your creative answer from the start :)

Comment: Got it sorry :-)

Comment: And there it was! Just changing the equality from `t.rnum - 1 = super.rnum` to `>=` solved the problem – I assured you that your answer will still help! ;)
Please feel free to update your answer with the change.

Answer (score 1):

Little wordy but I think it works

```
declare @t table (pk int identity primary key, id char(1), col1 char(1), col2 char(1), col3 char(1), col4 char(1), col5 char(1))
insert into @t (id, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) values
               ('g', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
             , ('g' ,'j', 'k', 'l', 'm','n')
             , ('g' ,'a' ,'b' ,'c' ,'d' ,null)
             , ('g', 'x', 'y', NULL, NULL, NULL)
             , ('g', 'x', 'z', 'w', NULL, NULL)
             , ('g', 'J', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
             , ('q', 'a', 'b', NULL, NULL, NULL)
             , ('q', 'x', 'z', 'v', NULL, NULL);
with cte as 
( select *
          , case when col1 is not null then 1 else 0 end  
          + case when col2 is not null then 1 else 0 end
          + case when col3 is not null then 1 else 0 end
          + case when col4 is not null then 1 else 0 end
          + case when col5 is not null then 1 else 0 end
          as cnt
  from @t t1
)

select t1.* 
from cte t1
where t1.cnt = 1 
  and not exists (select 1 from cte t2 
                  where t2.pk <> t1.pk 
                    and t2.id = t1.id
                    and t2.col1 = t1.col1
                    and t2.cnt > t1.cnt)
union all 
select t1.* 
from cte t1
where t1.cnt = 2 
  and not exists (select 1 from cte t2 
                  where t2.pk <> t1.pk 
                    and t2.id = t1.id
                    and t2.col1 = t1.col1
                    and t2.col2 = t1.col2
                    and t2.cnt > t1.cnt) 
union all 
select t1.* 
from cte t1
where t1.cnt = 3 
  and not exists (select 1 from cte t2 
                  where t2.pk <> t1.pk 
                    and t2.id = t1.id
                    and t2.col1 = t1.col1
                    and t2.col2 = t1.col2
                    and t2.col3 = t1.col3
                    and t2.cnt > t1.cnt)
union all 
select t1.* 
from cte t1
where t1.cnt = 4 
  and not exists (select 1 from cte t2 
                  where t2.pk <> t1.pk 
                    and t2.id = t1.id
                    and t2.col1 = t1.col1
                    and t2.col2 = t1.col2
                    and t2.col3 = t1.col3
                    and t2.col4 = t1.col4
                    and t2.cnt > t1.cnt)
union all 
select t1.* 
from cte t1
where t1.cnt = 5 
  and not exists (select 1 from cte t2 
                  where t2.pk <> t1.pk 
                    and t2.id = t1.id
                    and t2.col1 = t1.col1
                    and t2.col2 = t1.col2
                    and t2.col3 = t1.col3
                    and t2.col4 = t1.col4
                    and t2.col5 = t1.col5) 
order by pk;
```

Comment: Thanks @Paparazzi, in your query it seems that the primary key is required in the table, can this be achieved without it as well?

Comment: @Siavas Yes.  Use a cte with row_number()